# exposed beyond app through ClipData.Item.getUri

Tags: java, android

I am trying to fix a problem after the new feature added in Android file system but I get this error:

```
android.os.FileUriExposedException: file:///storage/emulated/0/MyApp/Camera_20180105_172234.jpg exposed beyond app through ClipData.Item.getUri()
```

So I hope some one can help me fix this :)

Thanks

```
private Uri getTempUri() {
    // Create an image file name
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss");
    String dt = sdf.format(new Date());
    imageFile = null;
    imageFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            + "/MyApp/", "Camera_" + dt + ".jpg");
    AppLog.Log(
            TAG,
            "New Camera Image Path:- "
                    + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    + "/MyApp/" + "Camera_" + dt + ".jpg");
    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/MyApp");
    if (!file.exists()) {
        file.mkdir();
    }
    imagePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/MyApp/"
            + "Camera_" + dt + ".jpg";
    imageUri = Uri.fromFile(imageFile);
    return imageUri;
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38200282/android-os-fileuriexposedexception-file-storage-emulated-0-test-txt-exposed

Answer (score 265):

For sdk 24 and up, if you need to get the Uri of a file outside your app storage you have this error. 
@eranda.del solutions let you change the policy to allow this and it works fine.
However if you want to follow the google guideline without having to change the API policy of your app you have to use a FileProvider.

At first to get the URI of a file you need to use FileProvider.getUriForFile() method:

```
Uri imageUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
            MainActivity.this,
            "com.example.homefolder.example.provider", //(use your app signature + ".provider" )
            imageFile);
```

Then you need to configure your provider in your android manifest :

```
<application>
  ...
     <provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="com.example.homefolder.example.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <!-- ressource file to create -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_paths">  
        </meta-data>
    </provider>
</application>
```

(In "authorities" use the same value than the second argument of the getUriForFile() method (app signature + ".provider"))

And finally you need to create the ressources file: "file_paths". 
This file need to be created under the res/xml directory (you probably need to create this directory too) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="external_files" path="." />
</paths>
```

Comment: "Make developers life easier" - this is the tagline for every new API, right Google?

Comment: The solution provided by Brendon is the correct one but it's not copy-paste ready, you need to check if it suits your needs, for ex. `<external-path ...` is used when you want Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().  and use `<files-path ...` if you need Context.getFilesDir().  You better check official docs first: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider

Comment: A reminder if you're using androidx (new support namespace), you can find here (https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/content/FileProvider) the proper documentation.

Comment: Note that in `androidx` it is: `android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"`

Answer (score 176):

Add following code block before start camera or file browsing

```
    StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder builder = new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder();
    StrictMode.setVmPolicy(builder.build());
```

Please refer the referral link [strict mode](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder) and its explained all the usage and technical details.

Comment: Its not the right way to solve this, this will basically remove the strictmode policies. and will ignore the security warning

Comment: There are some pros and cons on this. Please refer the following to get more information                  
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18100161/strictmode-threadpolicy-builder-purpose-and-advantages

Comment: It works, if there is any draw back then please let me know :)

Comment: The code solved the exception for me. However, the top comment here says how the code is not the correct way to solve this. Does anyone know what the proper method would be then?

Comment: Google hates programmers.

Comment: Thanks!!! It worked for me. But I will still investigate why the provider setting in the manifest is not working for me

Answer (score 4):

No required **provider** configuration into AndroidManifest only Camera and Storage permission should be permitted. Use the following code to start the camera:

```
final int REQUEST_ACTION_CAMERA = 9;
void openCamra() {
Intent cameraImgIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

cameraImgIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID +".provider",
                new File("your_file_name_with_dir")));
startActivityForResult(cameraImgIntent, REQUEST_ACTION_CAMERA);
}
```

After capturing the image, you can find your captured image in:

```
"your_file_name_with_dir"
```

Comment: It is better to explain the configuration of provider in AndroidManifest, than giving other code.

Comment: This worked for me with AndroidManifest <provider tag

Answer (score 0):

add a code in

```
onCreate(Budle savedInstancesState){
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 24) {
        try {
            Method m = StrictMode.class.getMethod("disableDeathOnFileUriExposure");
            m.invoke(null);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: getting file format not supported error for image.jpg

Comment: This trick no longer works on Android 11 :)