# Share intent issue in Instagram feed

Tags: android, image, android-intent, share

I have an app that shares images from url. Last android update, I got message from instagram "Unable to load image" when I want to share an image in instagram feed.

**But i can share image story, direct message, and everywhere... I am having this issue only instagram feed.**

```
public void onShareItemOreo() {
    // Get access to bitmap image from view
    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);

    // Get access to the URI for the bitmap
    Uri bmpUri = prepareShareIntent(imageView);
    if (bmpUri != null) {

        //outfile is the path of the image stored in the gallery
        // Construct a ShareIntent with link to image
        Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
        shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, bmpUri);
        shareIntent.setData(bmpUri);
        shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        shareIntent.setType("image/*");
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,marketLink);
        // Launch sharing dialog for image
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share Image"));
    } else {
        //
    }
}


public Uri prepareShareIntent(ImageView imageView) {

    // Fetch Bitmap Uri locally
    Drawable drawable = imageView.getDrawable();
    Bitmap bmp = null;
    if (drawable instanceof BitmapDrawable){
        bmp = ((BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
    } else {
        return null;
    }

    Uri bmpUri = getBitmapFromDrawable(bmp);// see previous remote images section and notes for API > 23
    // Construct share intent as described above based on bitmap
    Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
    shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, bmpUri);
    shareIntent.setType("image/*");

    return bmpUri;
}
```

Comment: try this: share.setType("image/jpeg");

Comment: @AliHas i have ("image/*)

Comment: Having the same problem, any news?

Answer (score 5):

**Update:** *This issue was fixed in the version of Instagram released earlier this week. Workarounds no longer necessary.*

---

None of the solutions mentioned above worked for me, as it seems that direct sharing via `ContentProvider` or its derivative `FileProvider` was broken by a change made within the Instagram app.

I did notice that sharing a `MediaStore` content Uri still works, as other apps such as Google Photos that write to the MediaStore prior to sharing were still able to share images to feed.

You can insert an image `File` to the `MediaStore` as follows:

```
@SuppressLint("InlinedApi")
fun insertImageToMediaStore(file: File, relativePath: String): Uri? {

    val values = ContentValues().apply {
        put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, file.name)

        val mimeType = when (file.extension) {
            "jpg", "jpeg" -> "jpeg"
            "png" -> "png"
            else -> return null
        }

        put(MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/$mimeType")

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
            put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH, relativePath)
            put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.IS_PENDING, 1)
        }
    }

    val collection = when (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
        true -> MediaStore.Images.Media.getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL)
        false -> MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
    }

    val uri = contentResolver.insert(collection, values)

    uri?.let {
        contentResolver.openOutputStream(uri)?.use { outputStream ->
            try {
                outputStream.write(file.readBytes())
                outputStream.close()
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
        }


        values.clear()

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
            values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.IS_PENDING, 0)
            contentResolver.update(uri, values, null, null)
        }

    } ?: throw RuntimeException("MediaStore failed for some reason")

    return uri
}
```

Then with that `Uri` that you're returned, share via Intent as follows:

```
    val filePath = "/data/data/io.jammy.withintent/files/IMG-20200321_093350_2020-122758.jpg" // this is an example path from an app-internal image file

    val context: Context? = this
    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
    intent.type = "image/*"

    insertImageToMediaStore(File(filePath), "Pictures/Your Subdirectory")?.let { uri ->

        val clipData = ClipData.newRawUri("Image", uri)

        intent.clipData = clipData
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri)

        val target = Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share Image")
        target?.let { context?.startActivity(it) }

    } ?: run {
        Log.e(TAG, "Unsupported image file")
        return
    }
```

Whilst it's not ideal, as the image is then written to the `MediaStore`, which may not be desired behaviour in many cases, it re-enables the ability to share in the medium term whilst Instagram fixes their whoopsie.

Comment: Thanks @MattMatt, I will try to do the same with Java, do you know if it possible? I'm not android/java developer há

Comment: You're welcome @mauriblint. It's definitely possible to do this in Java, in fact the Kotlin compiler creates Java byte code at build time under the hood anyway! This Gist might be helpful to you: https://gist.github.com/benny-shotvibe/1e0d745b7bc68a9c3256

Comment: Thanks a lot, @MattMatt! I could write the solution in Java following your Kotlin code, really appreciated, I have been dealing with this issue for almost 7 days

Comment: hey @MattMatt what about video sharing? Are any key values we need to change?

Comment: Hey @Choletski, you can, change the `MediaStore.Images.Media.*` calls to `MediaStore.Video.Media.*`, and ensure that you're setting the MIME type string to a video type that matches the file that you're sending. Here's a Gist that shows how to handle either an image or video file using the above method: https://gist.github.com/noln/584afabed1362fabbc2516275a5f755b

Comment: @MattMatt, it seems to work for me but on Android 10 I get an error:  `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Primary directory Videos not allowed for content://media/external/video/media; allowed directories are [DCIM, Movies]`

Comment: @Choletski That's not Android 10 specific, you need to put the media in the DCIM or Movies directory as the error says. "Videos" isn't a valid MediaStore prime directory. Check this line out: https://gist.github.com/noln/584afabed1362fabbc2516275a5f755b#file-mainactivity-kt-L84 It's also mentioned here in the docs: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/media

Answer (score 4):

Facebook is working on this bug, let's wait !
Subscribe to receive notification of updates to this bug report.
https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/1326888287510350/

Comment: Thanks, i have already subscribed. But how we know they are working on it.

Answer (score 1):

your uri is "content://packagename/xxx.jpg", it need to be "content://media/external/images/media/..."; it will be worked.

Answer (score 1):

[Problem solved with latest instagram update](https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/1326888287510350/)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I searched and found a solution. I do not know this is right way but solved my problem..

```
StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder builder = new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder();
StrictMode.setVmPolicy(builder.build());
```

[Found solution in this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48851566/1928396)

Comment: I got same error even using this, please confirm if still working for you

Comment: @Choletski , this is not for release mode. Just for debug mode.

Comment: @jancooth It's not working for me even in debug mode. Did you find any solution for release mode?

Comment: @GurgenGevondov i am still searching for t. If you found any solution, please update me.

Comment: @jancooth It seems to be an Instagram issue, because with older versions of Instagram apk everything works fine

Comment: hello guys, any news? I'm blocked with this issue :/

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Facebook already has the bug for this issue: https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/1326888287510350/

As a temporary workaround you can save media to MediaStore. This is the method we use to store and then return the uri for Instagram sharing.

```
    private fun insertImageToMediaStore(file: File): Uri? {

    val fileUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
        context,
        "${context.applicationContext.packageName}.provider",
        file
    )
    val mimeType = context.contentResolver.getType(fileUri) ?: "image/*"
    val isImage = mimeType.contains("image")
    val values = ContentValues().apply {

        put(
            if (isImage) {
                MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME
            } else {
                MediaStore.Video.Media.DISPLAY_NAME
            },
            file.name
        )

        put(
            if (isImage) {
                MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE
            } else {
                MediaStore.Video.Media.MIME_TYPE
            },
            mimeType
        )
    }

    val collection = if (isImage) {
        MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
    } else {
        MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
    }

    val uri = context.contentResolver.insert(collection, values)

    uri?.let {
        context.contentResolver.openOutputStream(uri)?.use { outputStream ->
            try {
                outputStream.write(file.readBytes())
                outputStream.close()
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
        }


        values.clear()

    } ?: throw RuntimeException("MediaStore failed for some reason")

    return uri
}
```