# "file:///storage/emulated/0/screenshot.png exposed beyond app through ClipData.Item.getUri()"

Tags: java, android-studio

I'm trying to set up a share button on my app. The button is supposed to take a screenshot of a particular list view, and then allow the user to share this image via whatever means they want. To do this, I created three methods:

1. Take the screenshot
2. Save it in my storage
3. Share it to the user.

To do this I've written the following code:

```
public class ViewPlayerHistoryContents extends AppCompatActivity {    

    public static File imagePath;

    public Bitmap takeScreenshot() {
        View rootView = findViewById(android.R.id.content).getRootView();
        rootView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        return rootView.getDrawingCache();
    }

    public void saveBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
        imagePath = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/screenshot.png");
        FileOutputStream fos;
        try {
            fos = new FileOutputStream(imagePath);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
            fos.flush();
            fos.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Log.e("GREC", e.getMessage(), e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("GREC", e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }

    private void shareIt() {
        Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(imagePath);
        Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        sharingIntent.setType("image/*");
        String shareBody = "In Tweecher, My highest score with screen shot";
        sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "My Tweecher score");
        sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareBody);
        sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);

        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share via"));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.view_player_history);        
        shareButton = findViewById(R.id.shareButton);    
        View rootView = getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content);

        shareButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Bitmap bitmap = takeScreenshot();
                saveBitmap(bitmap);
                shareIt();    
            }
        });        
    }
}
```

With this code I keep getting the following error message:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.transfergame, PID: 18477
android.os.FileUriExposedException: file:///storage/emulated/0/screenshot.png exposed beyond app through ClipData.Item.getUri()
```

Which to me sounds like it's because I'm using Uri and not FileProvider?

How should I be incorporating FileProvider in this?

I added the following permissions to my Android manifest file, but it hasn't done anything:

```
</application>        
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

How can I fix this error?

Thanks everyone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50265329/13722058)

You have add provider in android manifest and also create the a File Provider in xml/provider.xml as the answer in thus link suggests.

Answer (score -1):

```
public void captureImage() {
        StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder builder = new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder();
        StrictMode.setVmPolicy(builder.build());
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

        fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);

        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);

        // start the image capture Intent
        activity.startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE);
    }
```