# How to send text file via email as an attachment - Android?

Tags: java, android, email, email-attachments

I have looked at many codes online but all of them seem to run into a problem.

File is created and saved using the below function:

```
    private static String filename = "eulerY.txt" ;

    private void saveData() {

      

        FileOutputStream fos_FILE_eulerY = null;

        String message = "hello";
        try {
            fos_FILE_eulerY = openFileOutput(filename , MODE_PRIVATE);
            fos_FILE_eulerY.write(message.getBytes());
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (fos_FILE_eulerY != null) {
                try {
                    fos_FILE_eulerY.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }


        // export data
        sendEmail ();
    }
```

However, when running the below code to send the file, I keep running into the problem  `ClipData.Item.getUri`
And as suggested using all the answer from this link "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48117511/exposed-beyond-app-through-clipdata-item-geturi", when opening Gmail, it says "unable to attach file"

```
    private void sendEmail (){
        File filelocation = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath(), filename);
        Uri path = Uri.fromFile(filelocation);
        Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
       // set the type to 'email'
        emailIntent .setType("vnd.android.cursor.dir/email");
        String to[] = {"asd@gmail.com"};
        emailIntent .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, to);
      // the attachment
        emailIntent .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, path);
      // the mail subject
        emailIntent .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject");
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent , "Send email..."));
    }
```

I would appreciate it if there is any way to send this file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your `targetSdkVersion >= 24`, then we have to use `FileProvider` class to give access to the particular file or folder to make them accessible for other apps.

**Step-1:**
Add below code in `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

```
        <provider
        android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
    </provider>
```

**Step-2**

Create a `xml` folder inside `res` folder. And create a file namely `file_paths.xml` because look at above code inside `<meta-data>`.

file_paths.xml

```
<paths>
    <external-path name="external_files" path="."/>
</paths>
```

**Step-3**
Now you could save file inside your `package.private` folder and you can share `file uri` saved inside this folder to other app, for example `gmail` app as an `attachment`. Now your method looks like:

```
    private void saveData() {
    String filename = "eulerY.txt" ;
    //FileOutputStream fos_FILE_eulerY = null;
    File externalFilesDirectory = this.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS);
    File textFile = new File(externalFilesDirectory,filename);
    String message = "hello";
    try {
        //fos_FILE_eulerY = openFileOutput(textFile.getAbsolutePath() , MODE_PRIVATE);
        //fos_FILE_eulerY.write(message.getBytes());
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(textFile);
        writer.append(message);
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e){
        e.getLocalizedMessage();
    }


    // export data
    sendEmail (textFile);
}

    private void sendEmail (File file){
    //File filelocation = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath(), filename);
    //Uri path = Uri.fromFile(filelocation);
    //FileProvider.getUriForFile(it, "${it.packageName}.provider", file)
    Uri fileUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,getPackageName()+".provider",file);
    Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    emailIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    // set the type to 'email'
    emailIntent .setType("vnd.android.cursor.dir/email");
    String[] to = {"asd@gmail.com"};
    emailIntent .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, to);
    // the attachment
    emailIntent .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, fileUri);
    // the mail subject
    emailIntent .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject");
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent , "Send email..."));
}
```